# Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv= Exception in Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

My application contains an implementation of the "Service Locator" pattern. The ServiceLocator is a central component which performs (JNDI) lookups for Remote EJBs and is used by several of our applications/components (r6-core, Java-API, etc.). The ServiceLocator has several configuration options and its main goal is to enable flexible (machine independent/application independent) deployments scenarios. Another goal is to shield JNDI/EJB lookup boilerplate from business logic (code).

If a specific EJB is configured to be called only via local calls, the ServiceLocator implementation first instantiates an empty InitialContext and performs a JNDI lookup:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
ic.lookup(jndiName);
```

The currently unexpected behavior is that we get the following exception upon executing this code:

```
lookup for jndi-name 'java:global/.../ar-common-impl/ArPropertiesDaoBean' failed: 'Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv=
{java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
java.naming.corba.orb=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl@4f92338d,
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
com.sun.appserv.ee.iiop.endpointslist=corbaloc:iiop:1.2@sprprd01:23700}
```

This exception shows that a remote call is tried! Due to the fact that these (local only) EJBs are not configured to be remote beans (and thus not serializable) an exception is thrown.

The question is: Where does the endpointslist come from, even though we have not provided any of these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by using EJB injection rather than local lookups

Comment: Can you provide an example please, I am stuck with the error.